# Append Multiple .txt files into a single txt file, removing repeating headers and odd characters (carriage returns, etc)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder filled with .txt files delimited with "|". I need to append these all into a single .txt that I will query with power query, do manipulations to and summarize.

I found some VBA online that puts it into a worksheet, but the amount of rows in the .txt files require a different solution.

```
Private Sub ImportTxt()

'This worked best at combining files, but didn't remove headers
    Dim fso As Object 'FileSystemObject
    Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    Dim fl As Object 'File
    Dim Mask As String
   
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim newWS As Worksheet

Set newWS = Sheets.Add(before:=Sheets(1))
   
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") ' late binding
    'Set fso = New FileSystemObject 'or use early binding (also replace Object types)

    Set fldStart = fso.GetFolder("C:\mypath\TextFiles\") ' <-- use your FileDialog code here
    Mask = "*.txt"
    'Debug.Print fldStart.Path & "\"
    ListFiles fldStart, Mask
    For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
        ListFiles fld, Mask
        ListFolders fld, Mask
    Next
   

Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim L As Long, t As Long, i As Long
L = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
t = 1
For i = 1 To L
Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, other:=True, otherchar:="|"
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy newWS.Cells(t, 2)
t = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
WB.Close False
Next
myWB.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListFolders(fldStart As Object, Mask As String)
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
        'Debug.Print fld.Path & "\"
        ListFiles fld, Mask
        ListFolders fld, Mask
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles(fld As Object, Mask As String)
Dim t As Long
    Dim fl As Object 'File
    For Each fl In fld.Files
        If fl.Name Like Mask Then
        t = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Debug.Print fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
            If Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
            Else
            Sheets(1).Cells(t, 1) = fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried the following; however, i get a lot of odd characters and it seems to infinitely iterate.

```
Sub AppendTxtFiles2()
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim destinationFile As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    Dim isFirstFile As Boolean
    Dim lineData As String
    
    Call TurnOffFunctions
    On Error GoTo FireExit
    
    ' Specify the source folder and destination file
    sourceFolder = "C:\mypath\TextFiles\"
    destinationFile = "C:\mypath\Combined.txt"
    
    ' Get the first .txt file
    fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "*.txt")
    isFirstFile = True
    
    ' Loop through each .txt file in the source folder
    While fileName <> ""
        ' Get a free file number
        fileNumber = FreeFile
        
        ' Open the .txt file and read its content
        Open sourceFolder & fileName For Input As #fileNumber
        Do Until EOF(fileNumber)
            Line Input #fileNumber, lineData
            If isFirstFile Or Trim(lineData) <> "Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|...|Col13" Then
                ' Append the content to the destination file
                Close #fileNumber ' Close the file before opening it for appending
                Open destinationFile For Append As #fileNumber
                Print #fileNumber, lineData
                Close #fileNumber ' Close the file after appending
                Open sourceFolder & fileName For Input As #fileNumber ' Reopen the file for reading
            End If
        Loop
        Close #fileNumber
        
        ' Get the next .txt file
        fileName = Dir
        isFirstFile = False
    Wend
    
FireExit:
    Call TurnOnFunctions
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can have >1 file open at once - open the destination file outside the loop and then write all of the source file lines into the destination file.

Comment: @TimWilliams I didn't write this whole code, so I'm not entirely sure on how to execute that. in the second set of code, you're saying to move the `Open destinationFile For Append As #fileNumber` line outside of the `Do until` loop, but how would i write the to the file that way more specifically? not sure if moving that line only is the solve?

Comment: @TimWilliams tried moving that line outside the do until and outside the while and the macro didn't do anything. Currently it runs until i interrupt it, and the txt file doesn't open properly. So I'm kind of lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: Your write *"the amount of rows in the .txt files require a different solution."*. Why? How many rows? Do you actually need the combined text file for anything other than PQ? If not, just open and combine them directly in PQ and do the processing.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the reason was it could be millions of lines. I was able to get the vba to combine the files, is there a way for power query to take it hundreds of txt files appending them together?

Comment: If you have a `list` of the files (which you can generate dynamically by the relevant properties), you can use the `List.Accumulate` function to open and combine them all.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i have a folder with the files, unsure if that counts as a `list`; however, attempting to query the folder i end up with a bunch of the SQL completion time notes not being properly filtered causing issues and another error "[DataFormat.Error] We couldn't convert to Number."

Comment: A folder, by itself, does not ***count as a list***. A **List** has a very specific definition in PQ. But you can certainly create a **List** from the folder information using PQ. Since you show neither your code, nor a data sample that can reproduce your problem, hard to know what the issue is.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld exploring this avenue and some testing however, I was eventually able to pull in the folder, append the file and then put that all before my steps after a little troubleshooting. PQ is a bit cumbersome sometimes to figure what's exactly going wrong. I figured List vs. Folder wasn't the same, but going the folder route, the path being a variable seems to be a powerful combination that avoids a lot of effort by the computer comparatively. Thank you for at least inspiring it! Sorry if I wasn't more helpful in getting help.

Comment: @MarkS. I'm glad you are on your way. If you run into problems with the PQ code itself, probably best to ask a new question with appropriate data and code for more troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Sub AppendTxtFiles2()
    Dim rootFolder As String, sourceFolder As String, destinationFile As String
    Dim fileName As String, lineData As String
    Dim outNumber As Integer, inNumber As Integer
    Dim isFirstFile As Boolean
    
    ' Specify the source folder and destination file
    rootFolder = "C:\Temp\VBA\Folder1\"
    sourceFolder = rootFolder & "TextFiles\"
    destinationFile = rootFolder & "Combined.txt"
    
    'open the output file
    outNumber = FreeFile
    Open destinationFile For Output As #outNumber
    isFirstFile = True
    
    fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "*.txt") ' Get the first .txt file
    While fileName <> ""
        inNumber = FreeFile
        Open sourceFolder & fileName For Input As #inNumber
        Do While Not EOF(inNumber)
            Line Input #inNumber, lineData
            If isFirstFile Or Not Trim(lineData) Like "Col1|Col2|*" Then
               Print #outNumber, lineData
            End If
        Loop
        Close #inNumber
        fileName = Dir() ' Get the next .txt file
        isFirstFile = False
    Wend
    
    Close #outNumber 'close output file
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I was able to work out a solution. I did try this and it also worked. Neither yours or mine was able to eliminate the repeating headers, but thats because it seemed the txt file stored an unrecognizable character before the first text.